# `collection.sync()` doesn't work as expected [Kinto.js]

Tags: kinto

I have two clients `A` and `B` which performed this operations:

1. Client `A` created and .sync()ed a one record collection.
2. Client `B` .sync()ed and it received the collection with a single record.
3. Client `A` deleted and .sync()ed the collection. At this point there is no collection in both client `A` (checked via JS api and IndexedDB api) and the server (I checked with http calls).
4. Client `B` .sync()ed, but the record is still there.

I don't think this is the intended behavior. What could cause this?

---

P.S. Client A deletes with `virtual: false`, because it doesn't need the records in the local db anymore. Might that be it? Does this changes something on the server?

Comment: Do you have the record tombstone on the server? Can you try to read ``https://server.tld/v1/buckets/default/collections/you-colllection/records?_since=0`` ? What do you have there ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `virtual: false` you will never notify the server that you have deleted the record.

If you want to sync the deleted record status, you should not use `virtual: false`. It will get deleted locally after your next sync.

Comment: The server *is* notified. In fact, it removes the record from the db. If I pull I and don't find a record that's on the client, I would rather know. Instead this seems to be invisible to the client atm. There is no error, warning or message whatsoever. Plus, there are certain cases where it doesn't make sense to keep deleted records. That said, I love the current behavior, and I would also keep it as a default. It makes for a free out-of-the-box bin functionality. However, I think an option to opt-out from default behavior should be provided. I'm gonna post this over at github.